# How can I determine the screen size using addon SDK?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

How can I get the screen size using with addon SDK ?

```
var w = screen.width/2;
```

gives me an error : `Message: ReferenceError: screen is not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the window you have associated to your add-on; it's probably safer, because it will work even if the last visible window is closed but firefox is still opened (e.g. on OS X):

```
const { window: { screen }} = require("sdk/addon/window");
console.log(screen.width);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
var screen = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow().screen;
console.log(screen.width);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want multi monitor support I have a script but you have to understand it. It uses XPCOM, and it needs a range. This script only checks along the x axis, you should also check along the y axis.

So this is the script here that will detect all monitors in the x plane IF it falls in the y plane of 0-20 coordintates of primary screen, I don't recommend this method.

```
var sm = Cc['@mozilla.org/gfx/screenmanager;1'].getService(Ci.nsIScreenManager);

function getScreens() {
    var screen = null;
    var screens = [];
    var screenManager = sm;
    var min = 0;
    var max = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < 15000; x += 600) {
        var s = screenManager.screenForRect(x, 20, 10, 10);
        if (s != screen) {
            screen = s;
            var left = {},
                top = {},
                width = {},
                height = {};
            screenManager.primaryScreen.GetRect(left, top, width, height);
            screens.push({
                width: width.value,
                height: height.value,
                min: min,
                max: min + width.value
            });
            min += width.value;
        }
    }
    return screens;
}

var screens = getScreens();
console.log('screens:', screens);
```

#### This is the method I recommend

I needed to detect all monitor dimensons and had to resort to jsctypes, if you need that its here: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/workers/MainWorker.js#L853-L1523

That code is extremely long, thats because its getting all monitors and the taking screenshots of them. So you will want to extract just the monitors part. If you need help with it I can do it for you.